# Electron 8, GPU process hogs memory

Tags: performance, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I've built an electron 8 app.  It does some Computer Vision using tensorflow.js--modules are prebuilt by Google, so nothing custom on my end.  Typically the GPU process floats around 200-300mb RAM.  However somewhat randomly it'll go above 1gb and hang there and I can't figure out why.  The application runs in the background and only does processing randomly, so it's visually painful to have it consume so much memory when it's doing nothing.

- Any ideas how I could troubleshoot/debug the GPU process memory usage?
- Any ideas on ways to force the GPU process to free up memory it's holding on to?

I've tried disabling hardware acceleration--and while yes that fixes the memory issue, the CPU goes sky high when the app does the Computer Vision work.  I'd prefer it to hog more memory than impact the CPU that much.

Comment: HI @CamHart! Did you found any workaround or root of the issue?

Comment: No...  however I found that killing and restarting the renderer process that does the machine learning results in the RAM dropping back to normal levels.